Storing User Scores from Interactive Videos in a Database
I'm currently working on a project that involves creating interactive videos and storing user interactions, specifically scores, in a database.
My question is: Has anyone already found or developed a method to store user scores from an interactive video in a database? If so, could you please share your approach or point me to any resources that might be helpful?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've explored tools like H5P, ProProfs, and PopcornJS, but found limitations in controlling the score and storing it. I've also looked into other technologies like OneShot and WireWax.

Please provide further details on your setup. The answer is too broad

For H5P:
You will need to add your own piece of Javascript using H5P's alter_scripts hook. See the official documentation on customizing your platform.
That script can listen to xAPI statements that H5P uses to send information to the H5P Integration (aka plugin). This is also documented in the official documentation. If you need to, you can learn more about xAPI in its specification.
Your script can then send what it heard to the platform using common AJAX/XMLHttpRequest methods. You can then process all the information (way more than just scores) as needed on the server and store it inside a database the way you want to.

I sincerely appreciate your kind words, sir. Thank you for your appreciation!

Please vote the answer up then if you think it is useful.

When I attempted to write the script, I noticed that H5P was not recognized:
H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', function(event){
if (event.getScore() === event.getMaxScore() && event.getMaxScore() > 0){
console.log('test');
}
});

I assume you're just loading that script to your page. H5P content lives inside an iframe, and you will have to inject that script using the alter_scripts hook to load the script inside the iframe context (see https://h5p.org/node/2692 for your platform). Also, the document's readyState must be interactive or complete.

I mean, I saw your SNORDIAN’s H5P Resize Pulse on WordPress. I am actually trying to build from scratch and I realized that it is impossible to do so because the embedded H5P in my HTML and my JS just won’t work. Basically, they are not hosted on the same site. I am not using either WordPress or Moodle. Should I switch to one of them?

If you're embedding H5P from a remote server, you in fact cannot add custom scripts into the iframe. That would be a security nightmare. You also have no way to get hold of the xAPI statements - that could violate privacy. You will need to host the content youself - what H5P Integration you use (moodle, WordPress, Drupal, Lumi (node.js), ...) is up to you and depends on your needs and preferences.
